# Storing Long Array in Cookie

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I know the method of storing the data in php.
But this method doesn't work when I am storing a long array in PHP.
That array has about 3000 values (82382 characters).

I am doing this:

```
$encoded_db_data = base64_encode(serialize($query_result));
setcookie("db_select_result", '$encoded_db_data');
```

but **db_select_result** is printing blank (no value). How can i solve this problem?

Comment: [RFC 2965 §5.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2965#section-5.3) recommends that browsers support cookies of up to 4KB; most browsers do not support any more than that.  Therefore your data will not fit in a cookie (but do you really want such data to be stored in the client and transferred across the network anyway?).  Perhaps you should consider using PHP's [session storage](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), which is maintained server-side.  Or, if persistence is required beyond the session and given that your question is tagged [tag:mysql], store the data in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A user agent MAY ignore a received cookie in its entirety.  For
>           example, the user agent might wish to block receiving cookies
>           from "third-party" responses or the user agent might not wish to
>           store cookies that exceed some size.

From: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html

Consider the next options:

1.Split the array's data and put it in more than one cookie.

2.Use `sessions` (Unlike cookies they have "short-life") [http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php]

3.Store that data in a `Database` with a "unique key" , then set a cookie with that
unique key so you'll be able to identify which data to pull from the database.

4.Use less data from your array and try to put it in a cookie.